# Does max_packet_limit have an effect on the buffers?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently doing some database configuration on mysql to prevent our site from crashing I saw this variable

```
max_packet_limit
```

If I set a limit for this would this also put in effect to all the buffers even if I haven't put any limits on those? or I still need to set how much mysql should allot for the buffers as well?

Comment: Do you think the d/b server is crashing because it is low on memory?

Comment: Not really sure yet cause the site were running is accessed in many location and the site previously used the default settings of the database and we get the failed to connect to mysql we have alloted 1GB of ram for the site in digital ocean and suddenly it crashed so I tried to do some configurations over it to somehow prevent it from happening. To make mysql running again we have to restart the db server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the system variable **max_allowed_packet**.

This variable is not related to any buffer settings from MySQL.

max_allowed_packet is the maximum size of a SQL packet transferred between the client and the database server.

A packet is a single SQL statement sent to the MySQL server, a single row that is sent to the client, or a binary log event sent from a master to slave when replication is used.

More information: [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)